# Is there a minimum amount of urine that is considered "Going to the bathroom" for the purpose of making a blessing?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements, bathroom, asher-yatzar

After eating food or drinking beverage, we say a blessing; however, this is only the case if some minimum amount of food or beverage has been consumed.

Likewise, after going to the bathroom, we say a blessing. Is this blessing also dependent on the quantity of the waste released?

Answer (score 4):

There is no minimum amount below which it is not considered "going to the bathroom" for the sake of making a blessing. The *Shulchan Arukh* addresses this question explicitly:

> אֵין שִׁעוּר לְהַשְׁתִּין מַיִם כִּי אֲפִלּוּ לְטִפָּה אַחַת חַיָּב לְבָרֵךְ, שֶׁאִם יִסָתֵם הַנֶּקֶב מִלְּהוֹצִיא הַטִּפָּה הַהִיא הָיָה קָשֶׁה לוֹ וְחַיָּב לְהוֹדוֹת:‏
>
> There is no specific amount of urinating required, because even if one urinates a single drop one must bless ["who created man/Asher Yatzar"], because one's opening may have been blocked from urinating that drop and so it may have been difficult for him, and so he is required to give thanks.
>
> <sup>[SA - OC 7:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.7.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)</sup>

So if even a drop of urine is released, you should make the *asher yatzar* blessing.