# ברכת אשר יצר repeatedly

Tags: halacha, blessing, asher-yatzar

Is there a grace period as to how many times a person may relieve himself in an allotted amount of time and the recitation of Asher Yatzar? As in, one using the bathroom say three times in 10 minutes; Will they be obligated to recite three berakhos?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98501/asher-yatzar-on-numerous-occasions

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73277

Answer (score 2):

Given that even one drop of urine is enough to require a bracha, [Is there a minimum amount of urine that is considered “Going to the bathroom” for the purpose of making a blessing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73277/is-there-a-minimum-amount-of-urine-that-is-considered-going-to-the-bathroom-fo), then each time one goes would require a separate bracha. Note that [Asher Yatzar on numerous occasions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98501/asher-yatzar-on-numerous-occasions) explains that while one should say the bracha each time, if one neglects to say the bracha between times, one should only say the bracha once for all previous times.